# Action Buttons not showing up in ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I've been trying to follow the [official Android development tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) for a couple of days but I've noticed there's a few discrepancies between the two available IDEs, Eclipse with the ADT plugin and Android Studio. I heard nice things about the latter so that's the one I'm using, but there seems to be differences in the way the files are laid out when you first create a new project. I've mostly been able to solve stuff here and there so it works just like on Eclipse (the IDE used on the tutorial) but I can't figure out why my Action Buttons aren't showing up in the ActionBar. [Here's](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#AddActions) the tutorial for reference.

So, this is what my `res/menu/main.xml` file looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.example.myapplicationn.app.MainActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

All I did was replace `action_settings` and copy `action_search` directly from the tutorial's sample code. There's a subtle (maybe not that subtle) difference here between AS and the tutorial: the tutorial's file is supposed to be `res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml` but its AS equivalent seems to be the default file `res/menu/main.xml`, so I went with that. Also, the tutorial sample only has the first attribute (`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`), but the file created by AS had those additional ones so I left them untouched. Then, I modified the onCreateOptionsMenu method with this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Once again, the original code used `R.menu.main_activity_actions`, so I changed it to `R.menu.main`. The project compiles nicely and MainActivity shows up in my phone after a few seconds, but `action_search` is still hidden under the action overflow (isn't that what it's called?) button. Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated. English isn't my first language and my writing style is kind of lousy, so sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue recently.

The showAsAction property is in the app namespace. It is explained in the tutorial that it is used when using the compatibility library. But if you are targeting an API level high enough that shouldn't be needed.

I was able to use the android namespace and it works fine for me. So change app:showAsAction to android: showAsAction and it will show up where you want it.

Comment: Then the only other thing I can think of is to set the showAsAction property as "always" instead of "ifroom".

Comment: Damn, I already tried that as well. Maybe I'll try and start a new project and see if I can start from scratch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: Nope, still not there. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the activity which is creating the menu inherits from [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), which is the base activity class when using the support library.

Otherwise, whatever you set in `app:showAsAction` will not work.

I've scratched my head wondering why this didn't work for me in the past, dunno why they don't mention that in that tutorial you linked.

Hopefully this is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party. For those who still are having problem with this,
Try **Removing** this line

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and change

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

to

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

**IMPORTANT:**
Make sure that you PNG Image is not larger than 27x27

Comment: Funny thing is that Android Studio tells us to do exactly the opposite

Comment: @Vishwas Recommend way it to use app:showAsAction(...) But for this case it is opposite. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem while using Android Studio and following the official tutorial. Here is what worked for me, no idea why though.

1) I used the *ic_launcher* instead of the *ic_action_search* just to check if the search icon file itself had some issues.

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Now I could see that the launcher icon was visible.

2) Then I downloaded again the icons from the "Action Bar Icon pack" and changed the android:icon back to *ic_action_search*.

And now the search button is visible.

Like I said not sure why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Me too, have been following the tutorials, the link you have poosted. Same thing, the buttons just not show in the ToolBar, tried different solutions. Finally, one from Udacity is working.

Solution:
on your MainActivity, add the follwing code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu,menu);
    return true;
}
```

The rest is the same as the code in the official link, here, https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html#add-actions